# how to encapsulate a URL site into a Java object?

Tags: java, url, grails, encapsulation, java-io

I hava a Java/Grails app that needs to "read" the contents of a given URL to use it as an image, mostly to be dinamically resized.
My app already parses the url into HTML code using an implementation based on this post: http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/SourceViewer.shtml.

The class I built returns a String object that contains the HTML source code. Now I want to write this String into an object similar to a BufferedImage so I can display the captured URL into my new application.

any ideas, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an Image object from a url :

```
URL url = new URL("http://url.to/your/image.jpg";
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url)
```

Comment: Actually, the url is not a specific image path, it's a regular page, what I want to do is take a 'print screen' of the this site.

Comment: Wouldn't the HTML page you get have the URL to the image you need to capture?

Comment: yes, but there's a lot of images, so it is easier to take a 'print screen' of the page instead of take each image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service like [Bluga.net WebThumb](http://webthumb.bluga.net/home) and use Glen Smith's [ThumbnailService to interface with it](http://code.google.com/p/groovyblogs/source/browse/grails-app/services/ThumbnailService.groovy).

Or, if you really want to do this by yourself, you can use his [Thumbnail Server](http://code.google.com/p/groovyblogs/downloads/list) (with an [older version of the ThumbnailService](http://code.google.com/p/groovyblogs/source/browse/grails-app/services/ThumbnailService.groovy?spec=svncafcfc836748410d4ee6b046e57bd5ce777fea59&r=cafcfc836748410d4ee6b046e57bd5ce777fea59)), that he used to use before migrating to WebThumb ;)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If by

> take a 'print screen' of the this site

you mean display in your app take a look at this : http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.swing/how-to-display-pages-for-a-web-site-in-your-applic.html